# Why React components code doesn't get auto indented?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, indentation

I am using Visual Studio Code with React. But code indent doesn't getting applied automatically - I have to manually do it. It seems like working with text editor.

Sample code:

```
<Toolbar tabbar bottom slot="fixed">
        <Link bgColor="primary" textColor="white" onClick={() => AcceptOrder(self, order)}>
          <strong>
            {RootScope.t['Accept order']}
          </strong>
        </Link>
      </Toolbar>
```

I am using ES7 React/Redux/GrapQL extension.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any `Prettier` rules?

Also the default code formatting shortcut in vscode is `Shift+Alt+F` as you can check in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings